# keyboard layout switching on restart

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have two keyboard layouts that I use, My default keyboard is an USA layout, with a secondary Slovenian layout. I use the Slovenian layout only when I need some special characters when writing emails and such.

But my problem is this:

Every time I reboot my computer, the layout indicator shows I am on the USA layout, but the actual keyboard layout is Slovenian. Then I normally have to switch from USA to Slovenian and back, to get the layout I want.

Is there anything I can do about this? I don't restart my computer often, but when I do I forget about that, and typing the passwords like that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log out then before log back in select the Slovenian keyboard.
Now you can reboot safely ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot about that one. But it is still wrong that the tray icon shows a different keyboard layout if I change it in the login screen. But thank you for helping me out with this inconvenience.